# Can't add data to datetime2 field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Im using SQL Server Express 2008 and Im trying to add data to a field in a table which has a datatype of datetime2(7).

This is what Im trying to add:

```
'2012-02-02 12:32:10.1234'
```

But I am getting the error

```
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Does this mean that it's too long to be added to the field? and should be cut down abit? If so - can you give me an example of how it should look?

Note - I've also tried it in this format:

```
'01/01/98 23:59:59.999'
```

Thanks

**EDIT

The actual statement:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.myTable
( 
nbr,
id,
name,
dsc,
start_date,
end_date,
last_date,
condition,
condtion_dsc,
crte_dte,
someting,
activation_date,
denial_date,
another_date,
a_name,
prior_auth_start_date,
prior_auth_end_date,
history_cmnt,
cmnt,
source,
program, 
[IC-code],
[IC-description],
another_start_date,
another_start_date,
ver_nbr,
created_by,
creation_date,
updated_by,
updated_date)
VALUES
(
26,
'a',
'sometinh',
'c',
01/01/98 23:59:59.999,
01/01/98 23:59:59.999,
01/01/98 23:59:59.999,
'as',
'asdf',
01/01/98 23:59:59.999,
'lkop',
01/01/98 23:59:59.999,
01/01/98 23:59:59.999,
01/01/98 23:59:59.999,
'a',
01/01/98 23:59:59.999,
01/01/98 23:59:59.999,
'b',
'c',
'd',
'b',
'c',
'd',
01/01/98 23:59:59.999,
01/01/98 23:59:59.999,
423,
'Monkeys',
01/01/98 23:59:59.999,
'Goats',
01/01/98 23:59:59.999
);
```

Comment: Can you explain how you are "trying to add data to a field" - using what? Edit Top N Rows? An insert query? Something else? Are you including the quotes? Also is it possible the error is coming from a trigger on the table, or a different column?

Comment: That is a weird error to get when inserting on a `DATETIME` column. Can you show use the table definition, and the whole `INSERT`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand im using an insert query to do this and yes im including the quotes as i read that I needed them for SQL server. I can't show the whole insert statement as some info may be sensitive stuff

Comment: If you did everything right, it should work. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/39c0c/1

Comment: Uh, what part of your insert statement is sensitive? Just obfuscate it. If the column name is salary change it to sales or what have you. I'll bet a box of donuts it's one of the other columns in the insert statement, not this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a close look at the table you are trying to insert into. I bet one of the values you're trying to insert into a char/varchar/nchar/nvarchar column is too long.

```
SELECT 
  name,
  max_length / CASE WHEN system_type_id IN (231, 239)
    THEN 2 ELSE 1 END
FROM sys.columns 
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.TargetTableName')
AND system_type_id IN (167, 175, 231, 239);
```

This will get you a list like:

```
name    
--------  --------
col1      32
col5      64
col7      12
```

Now, compare this list to the literals you have in your `VALUES` clause. As I suggested in a comment, I bet one of these has more characters than the table allows.

There's a chance there are binary or varbinary columns, and the issue is there, but I strongly suspect this is a simple "string is too long" problem - and has absolutely nothing to do with your `DATETIME2(7)` value.